How to create a conventional way to create multi-component index mappings in Elasticsearch
Been messing with Elasticsearch for a while and I'm looking for a way to create a way/convention to create index mappings.
In detail, assume we have a domain model adopting multi-class extended hierarchy such like:
class Person : ClassA, ClassB, ClassC {
  str name;
  str surname;
}

class ClassA {
  int propertyA;
}

class ClassB {
  int propertyB;
}

class ClassC {
  int propertyC;
}

Which means Person itself has properties of ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
So according to my researches, I've realized that I can achieve this index mapping strategy with index templates and index components.
But since index templates puts their schemas over index_patterns, that would derive very long index names. (I might be wrong)
So I'm just looking for a mapping strategy which I can only append components on mapping schemas without obeying a index pattern or a similar stuff that affects the naming conventions of my indexes.
I'm open for any kind of suggestions on this scenario.
